# How to get the text from the Text Component within TouchableHighlight Component?

Tags: text, react-native

How can I get the text content from the Text Component within TouchableHighlight Component when clicked the TouchableHighlight component? Give me some idea to write the `handleClickMenu` function, thanks.

> some code as following:

```
<View>
  <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='#544b44' onPress={this.handleClickMenu}>
    <View style={MenuListStyle.menuItem}>
      <Icon name='heart' color='#df7454' style={MenuListStyle.menuItemIcon}/>
      <Text style={MenuListStyle.menuItemText}>GODDESS</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
  <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='#544b44' onPress={this.handleClickMenu}>
    <View style={MenuListStyle.menuItem}>
      <Icon name='rss' color='#03a9f4' style={MenuListStyle.menuItemIcon}/>
      <Text style={MenuListStyle.menuItemText}>BLOG</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
  ...
</View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to pass additional argument. In this case MenuListStyle.menuItemText that you can get in handleClickMenu

```
handleClickMenu(text){
     if(text === <something>){
        //do something
     }
}
render(){
...    
<View>
  <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='#544b44' onPress={this.handleClickMenu.bind(this, MenuListStyle.menuItemText)}>
    <View style={MenuListStyle.menuItem}>
      <Icon name='heart' color='#df7454' style={MenuListStyle.menuItemIcon}/>
      <Text style={MenuListStyle.menuItemText}>GODDESS</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
  <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='#544b44' onPress={this.handleClickMenu.bind(this, MenuListStyle.menuItemText)}>
    <View style={MenuListStyle.menuItem}>
      <Icon name='rss' color='#03a9f4' style={MenuListStyle.menuItemIcon}/>
      <Text style={MenuListStyle.menuItemText}>BLOG</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
  ...
</View>
}
```

Comment: Well, i get what you mean, it works. xD. And another question: can i use DOM operation in react native？

Comment: There is no DOM in react native. There is no DOM API. What were you planning to do ?

Comment: I just want to finish a navigation with react-native-drawer. Thanks for your big help.

Comment: No problem. You can use this.refs.<drawerRefName>.openDrawer etc.